# How to merge an entire dataframe only overwriting Nulls?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to figure this out but the examples I've seen are merged with only 1 column at a time. My situation is I have a large data frame with hundreds of columns - The good thing I'm trying to merge is the exact same size and same order.

Here's an example of what I'm struggling to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_withNaN = pd.DataFrame({
    'Hourly Rate': [20, 30, np.nan, 28, np.nan, 17, np.nan,22, 32],
    'Daily Rate': [72, 74,65,80, np.nan, 74,67,82,75],
    'Weekly Rate': [250,290,340,325,345,315,np.nan,248,265]})

df2_NoNaN = pd.DataFrame({
    'Hourly Rate': [30, 30, 50, 28, 80, 18, 20 ,220, 320],
    'Daily Rate': [72, 74,65,80, 88, 74,67,82,75],
    'Weekly Rate': [250000,290,200,325,345,315,45,24800000,265]})
```

This is what I am trying to get (only items that are `NaN` in `df_withNaN` are replaced with `df2_NoNan`)

```
{
    'Hourly Rate': [20, 30, 50, 28, 80, 17, 20 ,22, 32],
    'Daily Rate': [72, 74,65,80, 88, 74,67,82,75],
    'Weekly Rate': [250,290,340,325,345,315,45,248,265]}
```

I tried using merge but, like I mentioned, the examples aren't easy to implement on a DF as large as the one I'm working with. Any idea what I can do to achieve this?

Comment: `df_withNaN.combine_first(df2_NoNaN)` or `df_withNaN.fillna(df2_NoNaN)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang omg thank you. I actually had a long nested loop to go through and compare each cell then replace each item. By the time I hit line 30, I realized there must be a better way. Thank you. Do you mind putting this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't mind the answer as it's probably duplicated somewhere. Happy coding.